# fillRect method with image

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent, java-2d

I am trying to use the `fillRect` method in Java to fill a rectangle with an image. Is there a way to do it using the `fillRect` method?

Here is the code I was working on:

```
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    static int WIDTH = 1; 
    static int HEIGHT = 1; 
    private Image image = new ImageIcon("Golf_green.png").getImage();

    public BackGround() {
        WIDTH = 30;
        HEIGHT = 30;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT, "BLACK", , arg7, arg8, );
    }
```

Comment: The "add(new ImageViewer...)" within the paint method is a bad idea to start with. What framework? AWT/Swing/GWT/SWT/JavaFX?

Comment: I think you need to consult the JavaDocs and tutorials, as your drawImage call looks..."wrong"

Comment: You could use "BufferedImage#subImage" to "crop" a portion of the image and paint that

Comment: That rot above would not compile, let alone run.. 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) One way to get images for an example, is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Answer (score 2):

> (fill rect with tiled image) is there a way to do it using the fillrect method?

No.

Instead, tile the image across the width and height of the viewing area.  To get the effect that it is only for a particular rectangle, set that rectangle as the clip (prior to tiling).